# Converting nested list data into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a function that takes a list of data and constructs a dictionary that creates a key for each `data[0]` entry with a list of corresponding values that are links to the initial key entry. There should be repeats of the same value entry if there are multiple links.

Here is an example of the desired output:

```py
data = [("a", "b"), 
        ("a", "b"), 
        ("a", "c"),
        ("b", "c"),
        ("b", "a")]
        
data_to_dict(data)

# output
{"a" : ["b", "b", "c"], "b" : ["a", "c"]}
```

I wrote some initial code that is able to form the keys properly, but it only registered the last key-value pair instead of creating a list of all pairs.

My code:

```py
dict_data = {i[0]:[i[1]] for i in data}
    print(dict_data)

# output
{'a': ['c'], 'b': ['a']}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why `["a", "c"]` and not `["c", "a"]` does order matter?

Comment: Order does not matter, I just provided a sample data set to better help visualize what needed to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the values when you have duplicate values for a key. You need to add the list first and then append to it. You can do this with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or just use [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in data:
    d[k].append(v)

print(d)
# defaultdict(list, {'a': ['b', 'b', 'c'], 'b': ['c', 'a']})
 
# defaultdicts work like a regular dict, but you 
# convert if you need to for some reason
dict(d)
{'a': ['b', 'b', 'c'], 'b': ['c', 'a']}
```

Alternatively with `setdefault()`:

```
d = {}    
for k, v in data:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
print(d)
#{'a': ['b', 'b', 'c'], 'b': ['c', 'a']}
```